# Unable to perform OneToOne Mapping Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I was trying to implement OneToOne mapping using Hibernate. I am using Mysql as DB. I have Product as parent and ProductRestaurant as its child. Trying to get one to one maping between them but
While persisting, getting the following exception:

```
2015-12-13 00:06:24 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.A`enter code here`bstractBatcher - about to close PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 1, globally: 1)
2015-12-13 00:06:24 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.h.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - **Could not execute JDBC batch update [insert into myproduct (business_category, in_stock, merchant_id, productRestaurant, product_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'productRestaurant' at row 1**
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:1809) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.36.jar:5.1.36]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:1271) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.36.jar:5.1.36]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:268) [hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:184) [hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321) [hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51) [hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216) [hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:383)
```

When i print the queries, i found this.

```
 insert 
    into
        product
        (business_category, in_stock, merchant_id, productRestaurant, product_id) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Product Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product implements IEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "product_id")
    private String productId;

    @Column(name = "merchant_id")
    private String merchantId;

    public String getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(String productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }


    public String getMerchantId() {
        return merchantId;
    }

    public void setMerchantId(String merchantId) {
        this.merchantId = merchantId;
    }

    @Column(name = "business_category")
    private String businessCategory;

    @Column(name = "in_stock")
    private Boolean inStock;


    private ProductRestaurant productRestaurant;

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="product", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public ProductRestaurant getProductRestaurant() {
        return productRestaurant;
    }

    public void setProductRestaurant(ProductRestaurant productRestaurant) {
        this.productRestaurant = productRestaurant;
    }
    public String getBusinessCategory() {
        return businessCategory;
    }

    public void setBusinessCategory(String businessCategory) {
        this.businessCategory = businessCategory;
    }

    public Boolean getInStock() {
        return inStock;
    }

    public void setInStock(Boolean inStock) {
        this.inStock = inStock;
    }
```

ProductRestaurant Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product_restaurant")
public class ProductRestaurant implements IEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name="product_id")
    private String productId;

    /**
     * @return the productId
     */

    public String getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }
    public void setProductId(String productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    @Column(name = "category")
    private String category;

    @Column(name = "cuisine")
    private String cuisine;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "price")
    private Double price;


    private Product product;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    public Product getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public void setProduct(Product product) {
        this.product = product;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getCuisine() {
        return cuisine;
    }

    public void setCuisine(String cuisine) {
        this.cuisine = cuisine;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
```

Tables Created:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product` (
  `product_id` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `merchant_id` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `business_category` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `in_stock` tinyint(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product_restraunt` (
  `product_id` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `category` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `cuisine` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `price` int(7) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



ALTER TABLE `product_restraunt`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `PRODUCT_RESTRAUNT_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `product` (`product_id`);
```

What am i missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error is "Data too long for column 'productRestaurant' at row 1". So you are trying to insert something that is too long for this column to store.

Comment: productRestaurant is the entity object. It is not the column in the product tablr.I have its getter setter inside product entity. Hibernate is trying to pass the object directly, which i believe should not happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either set the `annotations` on the `Property(getters or setters)` or `Fields`, don't mix it.
In this case annotating the fields of the entity will cause the provider to use `field access` to get and set the state of the entity, if a `property acess` is present it will be ignored by the provider

Put the annotations of the bidirectional `@OneToOne` on the fields and remove it from the getters.

```
 @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
 private Product product;


public Product getProduct() {
    return product;
}
```

the same thing with the other entity.

Comment: Thanks a lot... That worked. But what's the difference.??   Also in the DB, extra column is added. Like in Product table, productRestaurant with null value added and similarly in ProductRestaurant table, product column is added with null value. does it work like that? i am new to this so dont have much info..

Comment: @Rohit you can find the difference here  : http://howtodoinjava.com/2015/04/21/field-vs-property-vs-mixed-access-modes-jpa-tutorial/